# Is Java RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN bug?

Tags: java

When I rounded a double number with HALF_EVEN mode , I found a problem, I don't know whether it is a bug of JDK? Please see the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RoundingMode mode = RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN;
    for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
        double d = i + 0.55;
        int scale = 1;
        process(d, scale++, mode);

        d = i + 0.555;
        process(d, scale++, mode);

        d = i + 0.5555;
        process(d, scale++, mode);

        d = i + 0.55555;
        process(d, scale++, mode);
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}

private static void process(double d, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode) {
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(d).setScale(scale, roundingMode);
    System.out.println(d + " -> " + b);
}
```

I expect to output:

```
10.55 -> 10.6
10.555 -> 10.56
10.5555 -> 10.556
10.55555 -> 10.5556


11.55 -> 11.6
11.555 -> 11.56
11.5555 -> 11.556
11.55555 -> 11.5556

.....
```

But actually, it outputs data like the below:

```
10.55 -> 10.6
10.555 -> 10.55
10.5555 -> 10.556
10.55555 -> 10.5556


11.55 -> 11.6
11.555 -> 11.55
11.5555 -> 11.556
11.55555 -> 11.5556
....

30.55 -> 30.6
30.555 -> 30.55
30.5555 -> 30.555
30.55555 -> 30.5556



31.55 -> 31.6
31.555 -> 31.55
31.5555 -> 31.555
31.55555 -> 31.5556



32.55 -> 32.5
32.555 -> 32.55
32.5555 -> 32.556
32.55555 -> 32.5555



33.55 -> 33.5
33.555 -> 33.55
33.5555 -> 33.556
33.55555 -> 33.5555

.........

62.55 -> 62.5
62.555 -> 62.55
62.5555 -> 62.556
62.55555 -> 62.5555



63.55 -> 63.5
63.555 -> 63.55
63.5555 -> 63.556
63.55555 -> 63.5555



64.55 -> 64.5
64.555 -> 64.56
64.5555 -> 64.555
64.55555 -> 64.5555



65.55 -> 65.5
65.555 -> 65.56
65.5555 -> 65.555
65.55555 -> 65.5555



66.55 -> 66.5
66.555 -> 66.56
66.5555 -> 66.555
66.55555 -> 66.5555
```

There are the same result in JDK 1.7/1.8

Is it a bug of JDK?

Comment: Why do you think this is a bug? And why bring BigDecimals into this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's part of life sadly, and due to the fact that `double` types are implemented internally with a radix of 2. For scientific programming this is a remarkably clever thing to do. But it does mean that when you want to view or specify them with a base 10 radix, what you see is not necessarily what you get.

For example, the literal `10.555` is actually a number slightly less than this (`10.5549999999999997157829056959599256515502929687...`) So apparent German rounding will actually round this number *downwards*. Your question contains many similar cases.

This is not a bug as such, but if you need precise rounding then you ought to use a class equipped to represent decimal numbers with arbitrary precision.

Using `BigDecimal` is an option but you are **misusing it horribly!**. By using the constructor from a `double` (i.e. `new BigDecimal(d)`) the imprecision endemic in `d` will be merely copied to the `BigDecimal`. So you ought to use the constructor from a `String` instead, or some similar approach.

Finally, take a look at http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter. Type in your decimal number and see the value that it assumes when converted to floating point.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug with the rounding mode, it's the way you create the BigDecimal.
Try the following:

```
 BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(d)).setScale(scale, roundingMode);
```

To create a BigDecimal you should not create it from the double value as mentioned [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_need_for_bigdecimal).

EDIT: It's better to use valueOf as stated in the comments and in the [api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-

Comment: BigDecimal.valueOf(double) will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.valueOf(d).setScale(scale, roundingMode);` instead.

As the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28double%29) say "This is generally the preferred way to convert a double (or float) into a BigDecimal, as the value returned is equal to that resulting from constructing a BigDecimal from the result of using Double.toString(double)."

Answer (score -1):

You should change your process method to:

```
private static void process(double d, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode) {
    BigDecimal unscaled = new BigDecimal(d);
    BigDecimal scaled = unscaled.setScale(scale, roundingMode);
    System.out.println(unscaled + " -> " + scaled);
}
```

That way you see the exact value before scaling.

Comment: This is the same as the question process method.

Comment: There is a difference, it prints the unscaled BigDecimal instead of the  double. Creating output like that 1.5549999999999999378275106209912337362766265869140625 -> 1.55